# Best way to have one product in both rental and sale parent category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I want to have one post type with categories displaying on the Sale and Rental page. I use ACF for custom fields so I can have both sale and rental prices.

How can I achieve the following example?

Example:

- Product name: Bike X
- Category: Bikes
- On page: Sale and Rental
- Sale page: sale/bikes/bike-x
- Rental page: rental/bikes/bike-x

I have one product in a category. And I want the categories and product displaying both on the Sale and Rental pages with different prices.

Comment: If your custom taxonomy is Rental, utilize `rental_price` custom field, else use `sale_price`.

Comment: I want first to show al categories on /sale and /rental and after choosing a category the product and then a product view like /sale/bikes/bike-x. Is this possible?

Comment: For the sale and rental pages, create a theme template use WP_Query to display only the ones you want. Having multiple permalinks to one post type may be possible but I would suggest you instead only offer one view of the single product that simply states both the sale and rental price.